# Find username in Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am managing membership with Cognito in my app. By the way, cognito looks for a password but does not provide a username lookup. Am I not looking for it? Or doesn't it provide functionality? So I try to find my id by storing it in mysql. How do everyone find usernames in Cognito?

Comment: Do you want something like: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html

Answer (score 0):

You might use [AdminGetUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html) to get a user from a given pool.

In python is like:

```py
from boto3 import client

_cognito = client('cognito-idp')

user = _cognito.admin_get_user(
    UserPoolId='Your-Pool-Id',
    Username='Your-User',
)
```

As suggested by @joe in the comments, you can also use [GetUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html) but you will need an access token.

```py
from boto3 import client

_cognito = client('cognito-idp')

user = _cognito.get_user(
    AccessToken='Your-Access-Token',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your user is authenticated and you have ID and Access JWT tokens for them you can decode those and they contain the user attributes like sub, email, etc. which might provide the information you need. There's example code [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/tree/master/Cognito/decode-verify-jwt) on how to decode each token but basically they're base64 encoded in three period delimited sections like aaa.bbb.ccc so you just split the string on '.' and base64 decode each section.